# Как изменить ресурсы класса

Tags: java

У меня есть настройки в виде txt файла, этот txt файл будет находится в jar архиве.

Я знаю как получать `URL` или `InputStream` этого txt файла через `getClass().getResources()` и `getClass().getResourceAsStream()` соответственно, но не знаю, как изменить его содержимое.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Модифицировать ресурсы в JAR-файлах нельзя.

Вы можете хранить в JAR-е настройки по-умолчанию и сохранять их во внешний файл или платформозависимое хранилище при первом запуске.

Comment: Жаль, так хотелось всё в одном месте хранить

Comment: Для хранения пользовательских данных есть рабочая директория.

Comment: в смысле простая папка?

Comment: Да, как правило, внутри пользовательской домашней папки (`System.getProperty("user.home")`)

Comment: Ну в принципе неплохо, но сработает ли например на Mac Os?

Comment: вернет что-то вроде /Users/ProstoCoder

Comment: Но я смогу сделать так File file = new File(Sysyem.getProperty("user.home)+"/App/Settings.txt");?